# In java every class extends Object.Then how it extend other class .Because one class can extend only single class

Tags: java

In java every class extends `Object`.But we know that one class can't extends more than one class.and when I create class A and it extending B,but A already extending `Object` class.How it become possible. What internally happen allowed to extends class B and `Object`.

This is only doubt.I know that it is managed by Java.Please suggest me.

Comment: its 'multilevel' .. not 'multiple' inheritance

Answer (score 4):

Each class can extend only one class, but this class itself can extend Object (or something that extends Object).

Thus everything class extends Object, even if there are some intermediate other classes.

For example, if you have classes `A,B,C` and `C` extends `B`, `B` extends `A`, and `A` extends Object, `C` is an `Object` because `C` is a `B` and thus it is an `A`, and since every `A` is object, `C` is also an `Object`

```
Object
  ^
  |
  A
  ^
  | 
  B
  ^
  |
  C
```

Answer (score 0):

Class A extends class B, when B extends Object. This makes A extends Object too.

Answer (score 0):

If Class A extends class B, then Class A can not extend Object. What happens is the Class B is extending the Object class or the Class B extends a class which is extending the Object class

Answer (score 0):

Every class is the **direct** descendant of only one class, but it is an **indirect** descendant of the ancestors of that class.

Think of it like this. A terrier is a dog; and a dog is an animal. In terms of a class hierarchy, you would have

```
Dog extends Animal

Terrier extends Dog
```

But the point is that a terrier is also an animal, **in virtue of** being a dog. So, in the Java world, the `Terrier` class directly descends from `Dog`, but it indirectly descends from `Animal`.

In this example, Java's `Object` would represent something like `Living Creature`, from which everything in the class hierarchy ultimately derives.

Comment: _"but it is an indirect descendant of the descendants of that class"_ -- don't you mean "but it is an indirect descendant of the **ancestors** of that class"?

Answer (score 0):

```
Object
  |_
    B
     |_
       A
```